# How to repeat method every 24 hours, by user input, when method is bool

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I want to repeat this notifications every 24 hours.
Temporary i`ve used `Thread.Sleep();` but i know this is not good solution.

I think about using Time.Interval BUT I don`t know where to place that methods.
when i set things like  `aTimer.Elapsed` and so on, according the documentation, My program just ignore the fact he need `_timePicker` input too.

My actual code looks like this

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        readonly INotificationManager notificationManager;
        DateTime _triggerTime;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), OnTimerTick);

            notificationManager = DependencyService.Get<INotificationManager>();
            notificationManager.NotificationReceived += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                var evtData = (NotificationEventArgs)eventArgs;
                ShowNotification(evtData.Title, evtData.Message);
            };
        }
        bool OnTimerTick()
        {
            if (_switch.IsToggled && DateTime.Now >= _triggerTime)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Alert", "Time to take your pill! :) ", "OK");
                string title = $"Pill Reminder";
                string message = $"Take Your Pill :) ";
                notificationManager.ScheduleNotification(title, message);

                var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                Vibration.Vibrate(duration);

                //24h interval, need some better solution
                Thread.Sleep(86400000);

            }
            return true;
        }

        void OnTimePickerPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.PropertyName == "Time")
            {
                SetTriggerTime();
            }
        }

        void OnSwitchToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs args)
        {
            SetTriggerTime();
        }

        void SetTriggerTime()
        {
            if (_switch.IsToggled)
            {
                _triggerTime = DateTime.Today + _timePicker.Time;
                if (_triggerTime < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    _triggerTime += TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                }
            }
        }
        void ShowNotification(string title, string message)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var msg = new Label()
                {
                    Text = $"Notification Received:\nTitle: {title}\nMessage: {message}"
                };

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use Timer `Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(24*60*60*1000), () =>
{
    // Do something
   
    return true; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
});` to fire notification.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this there are many different ways;

- repeatedly check for system TimeAndDate and run code once it gets to X.
- Shedule a task using a Timer. You can set interval to s/m/h and run code on TimerElapse.
- using a Thread Sleep, very very bad way in this case, for many different reasons.

Here's an example sheduling a task:

```cs
using System;
using System.Timers;
 
namespace ScheduleTimer
{
    class Program
    {
        static Timer timer;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            schedule_Timer();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void schedule_Timer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timer Start");
            DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
            //scheduled time HH,MM,SS [24 hours]
            DateTime scheduledTime = new DateTime(nowTime.Year, nowTime.Month, nowTime.Day, 24, 0, 0, 0); 
            if (nowTime > scheduledTime)
            {
                scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddDays(1);
            }
            double tickTime = (double)(scheduledTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
            timer = new Timer(tickTime);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Start();
        }
        static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timer Stop");
            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!\n");
            schedule_Timer();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how to use it for bool method?

Comment: @OliWeirdo be more specific please

Comment: I dont know how to apply your solution to my code. 
my code takes user input for set time of notification, and that is ok, but i dont know how to repeat notification after 24 hours (day by day), your code looks good, but I`m not sure it will be good for my case. Maybe I miss something....?

Comment: @OliWeirdo my code is just an example, you have to edit YOUR code as needed, implementing mine, schedule_Timer() and timer_Elapsed(...) are the keys.

Comment: But when I use it, according the documentation, ect, its not work. I can read, but I have not much experience, an that`s why I`m asking here. maybe there is one thing that i missed, that do the work.